# How to update one integer in a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

is there a way to update one integer in a list.

Lets say I have a list with the remaining space in some boxes, and i want to update it. how could i do something like this:

```
foreach (var itemToStore in items) {
if (boxCapacities.Any(bc => bc >= itemToStore.Size())) {
    var availableBox = boxCapacities.First(tc => (bc => bc >= itemToStore.Size());
    availableBox -= itemToStore.Size();
}
```

}

the problem with the code above is that the list has ints, and those are copied by value, so when I update the availableBox variable I'm not updating the one in the list.

Is there an elegant way to solve this problem without creating a new object just to encapsulate the integer?

Comment: Get the index of the "available box" and set that list index to that value directly, like `boxCapacities[availableBoxIndex] = newValue`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as sugested by Ron Beyer, using FindIndex does the trick

```
var index = boxCapacities.FindIndex(bc => bc >= itemToStore.Size());
if (index != -1) {
    boxCapacities[index] -= itemToStore.Size();
}
```

I'm still open for other solutions if they are more elegant or perform better

Answer (score 0):

Probably more complex, but just to explore possibilities you can have

```
foreach (var itemToStore in items)
{
    var idx = boxCapacities.Select((x, i) => new {index=i,ok= (x>=itemToStore.Size())})
                           .FirstOrDefault(k => k.ok);
    if(idx != null)
        boxCapacities[idx.index] -= itemToStore.Size();
}
```